# Angular Form Valid Observable subcribe cannot find onvalid event

Tags: angular

I am bringing in a shared form which has input control. I need to check if the form is valid. If it is false, the code will disable the save button.

In my angular html code, I have the following

```
<button  [disabled]="disablesavebutton" mat-raised-button 
(click)="save()">Save</button>
```

In my ts code, I have the following

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'


export class MyDialogComponent {
    disableSaveButton: boolean = false;
    baseControl: SharedComponent;

  ngOnInit() {
        this.baseControl.Form.statusChanges
        .filter(s => this.disableSaveButton = 
        this.baseControl.Form.valid)
        .subscribe(val => onvalid)
    }
}
```

My goal is the base form becomes invalid, the disableSavebutton boolean is triggered from subscribing therefore disabling the button. I am getting an error that "cannot find name onvalid. do you mean oninvalid" oninvalid expects an ev: Event parameter but I am unfamiliar with this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

In my angular html code, I have the following

```
<button  [disabled]="disablesavebutton" mat-raised-button (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

In my ts code, I have the following

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'


export class MyDialogComponent {
    disableSaveButton: boolean = false;
    baseControl: SharedComponent;

  ngOnInit() {

        this.baseControl.Form.statusChanges
        .filter(s => this.disableSaveButton = this.baseControl.Form.valid)
        .subscribe(val => onvalid)
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see any code defining an "onvalid" callback or any library that would have defined it. This disable-submit functionality can be done easily by checking the state of the form and seeing if it's invalid. https://blog.usejournal.com/angular-techniques-improve-submit-buttons-ux-by-not-disabling-it-896992a94a38

Answer (score 0):

The statusChanges Observable emits the current status of the form as a string.
To disable your button, you can simply check if the status is INVALID:

```
this.baseControl.Form.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
    this.disableSaveButton = status === "INVALID";
});
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges